# F# computation expression when is Combine called

Tags: f#, monads

I tried to implement this straight forward `Maybe` monad. So basically the whole expression evaluates to `Nothing` if one of the middle step is `Nothing`.

```
type Maybe<'a> =
    | Just of 'a
    | Nothing
type MaybeBuilder () =
    member this.Combine ((first, second) : Maybe<'a> * Maybe<'b>) : Maybe<'b> =
        printfn "Combine called"
        match first with
        | Nothing -> Nothing
        | _ ->
            match second with
            | Nothing -> Nothing
            | _ as a -> a
     member this.Zero () = Just ()
     member this.Bind((m, f) : Maybe<'a> * ('a -> Maybe<'b>)) =
        printfn "Bind called"
        match m with
        | Nothing -> Nothing
        | Just a -> f a
let MaybeMonad = MaybeBuilder()
let foobar =
    MaybeMonad {
        let! foo = Just "foo"
        Just 1
        Nothing
    }
```

I expected `foobar` be translated into `Just "foo" >>= fun foo -> Combine(Just 1, Nothing)`, however `Combine` wasn't called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not the way the computation expression is expected to be written. Each time you want 'yield a result' you need to add some keyword (return, return!, yield or yield!) on the left side of the expression, in your example I would add a `return!`:

```
let foobar =
    MaybeMonad {
        let! foo = Just "foo"
        return! Just 1
        return! Nothing
    }
```

But then you need to add its definition to the builder:

```
member this.ReturnFrom (expr) = expr
```

then the compiler will ask you to add a Delay method, in your case I think you're looking for something like:

```
member this.Delay(x) = x()
```

Almost there, now you have a value restriction, most likely because the `Combine` you defined doesn't use the same type on both arguments, you can either fix it or just add a type annotation in the return type:

```
let foobar : Maybe<int> =
    MaybeMonad {
        let! foo = Just "foo"
        return! Just 1
        return! Nothing
    }
```

That's it, now you get:

```
Bind called
Combine called
```

printed and:

```
val foobar : Maybe<int> = Nothing
```

If you want to understand all the details of CEs have a look at this nice article: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/the-f-computation-expression-zoo/

Comment: And then follow up that article with this very nice series of articles: https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/series/computation-expressions.html